# Start WPF Application with RunAs Prompt

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-services, sysinternals

So I have a WPF application and here is what I want it to do.  I can right click on the executable, select Run As Different user, and get the Windows Security box with User Name and Password, as well as the Smart Card logon.  I was wondering if there was a way to launch the Sysinternals Run as Different User to come up automatically, without having to right click and select Run As Different User.  Any thoughts?

I was able to go into the Assembly Manifest and force it to run as administrator, but that isn't what I need.  I really need the option to run it with Smart Card credentials.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the only way to do it that works is by using the `RunAs exe` as follows. The `/savecred` will cache credentials, but your user will still have to enter it the very 1st time (which might be annoying for your use-case).

```
runas.exe  /savecred /user:<localmachinename>\administrator "path to your WPF exe"
```

or, if you're on a domain:

```
runas.exe  /savecred /user:<DomainName>\<AdministratorAccountName> "path to your WPF exe"
```

Example: To Run Visual Studio 2012 in Admin Mode, I tried the following and it worked. I was prompted to enter my password just once, for the 1st time.

```
runas.exe  /savecred /user:<My_DomainName>\<My_AdministratorAccountName>  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

**Further Reading:** [Runas Documentation.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks - I see what you are getting at.  What I am looking for is a smidge different I think.  I am looking to have the WPF application open itself with the prompt, not open another program.  My program is an Active Directory replacement that requires I IT staff to use their security token to reset passwords.  I can't have it run as administrator, but need to have the entire application use the Smart Card credentials.  Does that make sense?

Comment: So basically I am starting with the desktop and am clicking on the icon for my executable that is created through WPF.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Sorry my answer didn't help. I'll keep looking and let you know if I find out a way...

Comment: Actually I think you could be on to something - looking in the Runas Documentation there is a /smartcard option stating - Indicates whether the credentials are to be supplied from a smartcard. This parameter cannot be used with the /savecred parameter.

Comment: Cant you right click the exe file and select always run as administrator?

Comment: wonder if there would be a way to start the entire application that way.

Comment: Cool. Try it and let us know if it works. I'm heading home now, will logon later and also try it.

Comment: Atomaras - Don't want to run as administrator though - want to run with smartcard creds

Comment: @Shiva - So I was able to sort of get it...  I started a command prompt and typed the folloing:  runas /smartcard /user:<mydomain>\<mysmartcardusername> "path to exe"  and it worked.  Any thoughts on how to integrate this into the application - perhaps without using a cmd prompt?

Comment: @kenny  Not really - ideally I just want to click on the icon to bring up the different "run as different user" options.  I was able to create a shortcut to my application and then in the target add C:\Windows\System32\ShellRunas.exe before the target - which works the way I want it to, however, I can't seem to emulate it within C#

Comment: Sounds like a custom app then.